# How can I create a project in gcp via terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am planning to use terraform to deploy to GCP and I have read the instruction on how to set it up:

```
provider "google" {
  project = "{{YOUR GCP PROJECT}}"
  region  = "us-central1"
  zone    = "us-central1-c"
}
```

it requires a `project` name in the `provider` configuration. But I am planning to create the project via terraform like below code:

```
resource "google_project" "my_project" {
  name       = "My Project"
  project_id = "your-project-id"
  org_id     = "1234567"
}
```

how can I use terraform without a pre-created project?

Comment: So what's the problem? Do you have pre-existing google organization?

Comment: I have pre-existing google organization but no project

Comment: You will need to create a project and assign a billing account first. Then you can create projects using Terraform.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao Were you able to get the project provisioned? Easy testing route would be to login to GCP, open Cloud Shell (should be authenticated at this point), create your `.tf` files in a directory at the CLI and run the normal `init  > plan > apply`. At a minimum you should need an `org_id`, `billing_account`, and `project_id`. You shouldn't need to have an already created project in order to provision this new project. If you wanted to use something like Cloud Build (CI/CD) to provision a new project in GCP then you would need a pre-existing project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on this tutorial (from Community):

[Creating Google Cloud projects with Terraform](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/managing-gcp-projects-with-terraform)

This tutorial assumes that you already have a Google Cloud account set up for your organization and that you are allowed to make organization-level changes in the account

First step,for example, is to setup your ENV variables with your Organization ID and your billing account ID which will allow you to create the projects using terraform:

```
export TF_VAR_org_id=YOUR_ORG_ID
export TF_VAR_billing_account=YOUR_BILLING_ACCOUNT_ID
export TF_ADMIN=${USER}-terraform-admin
export TF_CREDS=~/.config/gcloud/${USER}-terraform-admin.json
```